# Comparing standard errors obtained from error analysis to calculated values

Tags: standard-deviation, error-propagation

Say I have completed some error analysis on a function and determined that the error in a particular variable ought to be ± 0.05 m for a particular variable. If I had a dataset of measurements made of the variable and used a standard formula for obtaining the standard error in the measurements, is there a good way to compare these two values (a predicted vs calculated value)?

I have only used F-tests to compare variances before, but I do not think these are suitable in this case because of the calculated value having no degrees of freedom.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome to CV. I'm wondering for which value you have calculated. Is it the variance (error) of the value itself? If this has only a singular value from your theory, then you can at least check agreement with the measurement. But it's not clear what kind of statement/analysis you are interested in, comparing these variances.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I calculated the variance of the value using error analysis, which is indeed a single value. I was wondering if there were a quantitative way of comparing the two values, other than saying that they are of the same magnitude? I am unfamiliar with any methods that would otherwise help me compare the two.

Comment: My first guess would be to use "standard" hypothesis testing. Which one of the many available variants might be best suited would be another issue. But this is the standard way to compute (or express) the compatibility between two values.